# Indy 10 Delphi FTP Client Demo Error

Tags: delphi, ftp, client, indy10

I am new to Delphi and wanted to try breaking down a demo to understand the it's structure.

I am trying to get the Indy 10 Delphi FTP Client demo to run on Delphi XE2.

Whenever I run the downloaded code, I enter the FTP URL, Username, Password etc and when the FTP connects this error appears:

> raised exception class $C00000005 with message 'access violation at
>   0x0018f90e: write of address 0x0000000'

Which I assume it means it's pointing at a null?

The debugging tool simple points at this line..

```
ChangeFTPDir(Sites[cbFTPAddress.ItemIndex].RootDir);
```

What would be the best way of removing this error (try/catch) or is there a working sample of a Delphi FTP procedure that I could have a look at?

Thanks for your time in advance,

Sophie

The procedure is as below:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ChangeFTPDir(NewDir: String);
begin
  FLastDirStack.Add(FTP.RetrieveCurrentDir);
  FTP.ChangeDir(NewDir);
  DisplayFTP;
end;
```

I assume that the site array does contain details as the ftp does connect to the name of the stored ftp site before the error appears...

Comment: Yes, the error means a nil pointer is being written to. Did you verify that `Sites[]` is allocated and that `ItemIndex` is greater than 0? What does the code for `ChangeFTPDir()` look like?

Comment: procedure TfrmMain.ChangeFTPDir(NewDir: String);
begin
  FLastDirStack.Add(FTP.RetrieveCurrentDir);
  FTP.ChangeDir(NewDir);
  DisplayFTP;
end;

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `IdAllFTPListParsers` ? Try it.